# Serve only one subdomain out of several with jetty

Tags: jetty, jetty-8

Multiple domains and subdomains are pointing to my server. 
I want to serve only one or two of them with jetty over 8080 the rest should be ignored by jetty.

Is there a way to do this? (OK, I am sure there is one but I could not figure out how)
I am using Jetty 8 on Ubuntu 12.04

thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you want to work with is Virtual Hosts.
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Virtual_Hosts

However, note that this applies to the webapp you deploy, not all of jetty.
This is because Jetty will bind/listen to port 8080 on the interfaces (IP addresses) you specify, and has to accept the connection, accept the HTTP request, and then make its determination on what hostname / domain the browser is asking for.

Comment: That's what I already did. It works fine for the two subdomains where I need 8080 (jetty) but it brings the jetty 404 error-page for all the other domains including the "available context"-info.

Comment: Found a solution on:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+Create+Custom+Error+Pages

"One of the quickest ways to avoid this behavior is to create a catch all context. Create a **"root" web app** mapped to the "/" url. Have the **index.html redirect to whatever** place with a header directive."